# Read JSON file in a directory and its sub-directories

Tags: node.js

I have a file named `file.json` in the `/assets` directory and some of its subdirectories as well. Is there a way that I can search the `assets` directory and read each of the `file.json` file using the `fs.readFileSync` method at once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if you can do it synch, yet, you can use [glob](https://www.npmjs.com/package/glob) and [stream-concat-files](https://www.npmjs.com/package/stream-concat-files). Note the the concat by default is to a file but you can stream it to a a string buffer writeable stream.

```
glob('asset/**/file.json', function(err, files){concatFiles(files, 'concat.json', function(err){})});
```